# How can I use the TRACE macro in non-MFC projects?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

I want to use the TRACE() macro to get output in the debug window in [Visual Studio 2005](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2005) in a non-[MFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Class_Library) C++ project, but which additional header or library is needed?

Is there a way of putting messages in the debug output window and how can I do that?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Build your own.

trace.cpp:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
bool _trace(TCHAR *format, ...)
{
   TCHAR buffer[1000];

   va_list argptr;
   va_start(argptr, format);
   wvsprintf(buffer, format, argptr);
   va_end(argptr);

   OutputDebugString(buffer);

   return true;
}
#endif
```

trace.h:

```
#include <windows.h>
#ifdef _DEBUG
bool _trace(TCHAR *format, ...);
#define TRACE _trace
#else
#define TRACE false && _trace
#endif
```

then just #include "trace.h" and you're all set.

Disclaimer: I just copy/pasted this code from a personal project and took out some project specific stuff, but there's no reason it shouldn't work. ;-)

Comment: wvsprintf does not handle floating point numbers (%f). Instead, vsprintf can be used.

Comment: For Linux C++, I modified your code with `#include <stdarg.h>`, `#include <cstdio>`, replaced `wvsprinf` with `vsnprinf`. Then replaced `OutputDebugString` with `std::clog << buffer << std::flush;`.

Comment: In release builds, Visual Studio generates a warning C4013 (warning level 3) and also warnings C4555 (warning level all) for each TRACE occurrence. To prevent the warnings, I changed the `false && _trace` part into `__noop`. This is also the way MFC does it.

Answer (score 9):

If you use ATL you can try ATLTRACE.

TRACE is defined in afx.h as (at least in vs 2008):

```
// extern ATL::CTrace TRACE;
#define TRACE ATLTRACE
```

And ATLTRACE can be found in atltrace.h

Comment: I wanted to use this this approach however there is some additional ATL baggage that comes along with this for a project that is not ATL.  I am working with C++/CLI with Window Forms and adding the `atltrace.h` include caused compiler errors so I took the approach of just using `OuputDebugString()` instead since I just have a few text strings to output at various places.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the DebugOutputString function. TRACE is only enabled in debug builds.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to these answers I have fixed my bug :-)

Here I share my TRACE macro in C++ based on ideas from Ferruccio and enthusiasticgeek.

```
#ifdef ENABLE_TRACE
#  ifdef _MSC_VER
#    include <windows.h>
#    include <sstream>
#    define TRACE(x)                           \
     do {  std::stringstream s;  s << (x);     \
           OutputDebugString(s.str().c_str()); \
        } while(0)
#  else
#    include <iostream>
#    define TRACE(x)  std::clog << (x)
#  endif        // or std::cerr << (x) << std::flush
#else
#  define TRACE(x)
#endif
```

example:

```
#define ENABLE_TRACE  //can depend on _DEBUG or NDEBUG macros
#include "my_above_trace_header.h"

int main (void)
{
   int     v1 = 123;
   double  v2 = 456.789;
   TRACE ("main() v1="<< v1 <<" v2="<< v2 <<'\n');
}
```

Any improvements/suggestions/contributions are welcome ;-)

Comment: I got error when tried to use it: 
Error (active) E2140 expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding wvsprintf has problem with formatting. Use _vsnprintf (or thcar version _vsntprintf ) instead

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the following on the 'net:
`#define TRACE printf`

Developing this a little bit, came up with the following:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define TRACE printf
#else
#define TRACE 
#endif
```