# TRACE Macro in VS2015 / 2017 wont compile - what do i need to include?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, trace

I have an SDK for some Hardware I need to implement
I use The MFC Class they provide and created a windows console application.
They heavily rely on the Trace Macro so i cant simply comment them out.

- I already manually installed the ATL + MFC Component for visual C++
- I installed the 2015 Compiler (as i read they changed something ...)
- I disabled precompiled headers
- I tried "switching" some options in Project properties, but that did not yield anything different :(

  TRACE(_T("PS10DLL not found\n"));

I would expect to compile smoothly but the Error (they used it alot) is:
`error C3861: "TRACE": Identifier was not found.`

Comment: According to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/6w95a4ha(v=vs.140)) you need to include the afx.h header file

Answer (score 0):

According to your issue, you are creating a windows console application? TRACE is used in the MFC support program and cannot be used in the WIN32 Application program.

TRACE is a definition in MFC. In Win32 code, you can directly use [OutputDebugString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-outputdebugstringw) to achieve the same effect.

I suggest you could refer to the link: [How can I use the TRACE macro in non-MFC projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494653/how-can-i-use-the-trace-macro-in-non-mfc-projects)